# What are the secret/missable achievements in Gunpoint?

Tags: gunpoint

What are the requirements for the secret achievements in Gunpoint?  And which achievements *(secret or not)* are missable during a normal playthrough?

Comment: As late as it is, was *that* \/ the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are guides all over the internet one click away, but I'll answer it anyway...

Everything I am about to say is coming from personal experience and from this page:
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=150411310

**SPOILER ALERT:** Everything below this line contains info on HOW to get the achievements. I don't know if you want to know, or if you already do, but it's just a heads-up.

---

### **Achievements that WILL be obtained in a regular playthrough**

**Rooke Sympathiser** ***OR*** **Intex Sympathiser**
For **Rooke**, Steal the technology from Gessler.
For **Intex**, tell Gessler that Rooke hired you for betrayal.

**Cover Up** ***OR*** **Clean Record** ***OR*** **Hammerhead Shark**
For **Cover Up**, dont tell **Mayfield** about your involvement in the DataSec break-in.
For **Clean Record**, don't get caught on ANY cameras in the mission **Mayfield: The Room** and give him the REAL file. (It's fake anyway, don't worry)
For **Hammerhead Shark**, (From the Achievement Page):
Let Mayfield discover your involvement, then during your final conversation with the police chief (mission: "Mayfield: The Room"), choose either "I hope you have a good morgue. And I've been there, you don't." or "Shouldn't you be hoping I have a bad one?"

**Let it Go** ***OR*** **Payback**
For **Let it Go**, let out the truth for **Jackson**.
(Complete **Jackson: The Truth** which is (one of the two) the last mission of the game)
For **Payback**, catch the assassin for **Rooke** and don't help Jackson.
(Complete **Rooke: The Killer** which is (one of the two) the last mission of the game)
(The assassin will be outside Gessler's office)

**Case Closed** - Beat the game.
**Case Filed** - Make a personalised blog (Assuming you play after the game where you basically talk to yourself (blog) about the game itself).
**Acknowledged Ludonarrative Dissonance**
During the creation of the blog, choose the choices that make no sense.
From [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/206190/discussions/0/864969953413336692/),
**Zork Nemisis**: Pick the sarcastic and non-sequiter choices. Easier yet, choice 3 all the way.

Uh oh, this ones going to be a pain to do... xD

**(1) Knuckle Down** ***OR***
**(2) I Just Really Don't Like Gessler** ***OR***
**(3) Why Don't You Just Shoot Him?** ***OR***
**(4) Those Intex Models Jam** ***OR***
**(5) Seven Story Takedown** ***OR***
**(6) Not Worth The Bullet** ***OR***
**(7) Sorry, Were You Using That?** ***OR***
**(8) Works Both Ways**

**(1)** Punch **Gessler** and knock him out (one punch will do)
**(2)** Punch **Gessler** to death (spam dat mouse button like no-ones business)
**(3)** Shoot **Gessler** with the **Resolver**.
**(4)** Rewire **Gessler's** gun so it doesn't shoot.

**(5)** Knock **Gessler** out his window. (Repeatedly jumping on him to the point where you BOTH fall out works fine)

**(6)** Hold **Gessler** to gunpoint and go through the dialog, he will drop his gun. (Now would be a good time to get the **Seven Story Takedown** achievement as he stands idly.

**(7)** Use the **Gatecrasher** to smash the door into **Gessler** (Getting him to drop his gun first and THEN smashing the door works fine)

**(8)** Get **Gessler** to drop his gun, push him to the door, rewire, and slam it on him.

And **THAT** is the list of regular gameplay ones... Damn that was a big last part. wew!
***PS:*** You can quicksave before killing **Gessler** to get the above 8 achievements. Just make sure you have the proper equipment bought for it.

---

### **Achievements that are OPTIONAL in any playthrough**

**Warning** - all achievements must be done **OUTSIDE** the test lab. (This only counts for some as the rest can't be done in there anyway)

**Cat Burglar** - Use the **Dropshot** and land silently.
**On the QT** - Use the **Hushcracker** to silently jump through a window.
**Not Really A Prank, Man** - Use the **Prankspasm** on someone.
**Crossfire** - Use the **Longshot** to make a guard accidentally shoot another.
**Title Finally Relevant** - Aim the **Resolver** at a guard. (Preferably not a Professional xD)
**Breaking And Entering** - Smash a door down with the **Gatecrashers**
**Low Flying Doors** - Hit a guard with a smashed door with the **Gatecrashers**

**Might As Well Have An Achievement For That Too** - Smash a door through a window with the **Gatecrashers**

**Open Door Policy** - Close a door on a guard.
**So This Is Why People Don't Like Me** - Get a door closed on you.

**Alright, Have One! Just Stop!**
Basically just punch a guard a couple of hundred times, some dialogue will appear, "There's no achievement for this!", couple more, and you get the achievement. Note: After the counter appears, there's no more additional dialogue, so don't try.

**Mission Architect** Make a custom mission with one or more objectives. (Just put a player, computer and station. Done!)

**I'll Aim When I'm Dead** - Upgrade your jump speed to max. (Note, you can just minus all your points when you get it and use it for the others)

**I May Be Some Time** - Upgrade your jump height to max.
**I Taste Battery Acid** - Upgrade your battery capacity to max.
**Necessary Force** - Push an enforcer out a window via. jumping at him.
**Ding** - Make an elevator activate something as it arrives.

**Short Circuit** - Wire an infinite loop and burn it out. (Just wire two lights on the same floor (appears in some levels) and loop it all together and activate it)

**I Am Better At This Than Tom Francis** - Go on an early mission after beating the game, get all upgrades, slam through the level as fast as possible, it's easy.

**Ghost** - Don't let a guard see you. If he does, kill him. (Punching once won't do it, spam it for a while)

**Gentleman** - Don't hurt ANYONE on a mission with guards.
**Perfect Gentleman** - Finish a level with guards without loud noises, witnesses or violence.